# Can Neo4j property order be controlled?

Tags: neo4j

Is there any mechanism for controlling the order of properties?

I cannot reproduce this in http://www.neo4j.org/console

Using Neo4j 1.9.2 Community if I do the following:

```
CREATE (m1 {`$type`: {moduleTypeName}, Name: 'M1', ModelNumber: 'MN1'})
```

Then later I get this node back from a cypher query using the REST cypher endpoint I get back...

```
{
    "extensions": {},
    "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
    "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships/out",
    "traverse": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/traverse/{returnType}",
    "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
    "property": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/properties/{key}",
    "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships/all",
    "self": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777",
    "properties": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/properties",
    "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
    "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships/in",
    "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
    "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/3777/relationships",
    "data": {
        "ModelNumber": "MN1",
        "$type": "ModuleType",
        "Name": "M1"
    }
}
```

I'm using http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx to parse JSON and for it to automatically infer an object type, the $type property must be first.  It makes sense when parsing the JSON in a stream when you don't want to load the entire thing into memory first.

It does not appear to be alphabetical, and it does not seem to be random either.  It seems that the order is consistent for different object types, but inconsistent between them.

I have pulled the node in the Shell as well and so it seems that the order does not depend on how I get the node, but is not related to the order in which I create the node either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties have no guaranteed order. Do not take any assumptions on a 'maybe' ordering. An upcoming version might change this assumed behaviour and break your code.

I guess it is simpler in Cypher to not return the node itself in favour of a list of properties, e.g.

```
START node=node(<myid>)
RETURN node.`$type`, node.ModelNumber, node.Name
```

This has defined columns.

Comment: Unfortunately the cypher returns the properties in a {columns:[], data:[]} sort of way that make it a little crazier for a POJO/POCO mapping.

Comment: If you use only the data part of the json response you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Definitively it seems not to have that functionality.
My workaround for it it is to alias the properties with a prefix in the format aXX_, as in a01_, a02, a03_ and then remove it in the code.
Not pretty, not great, but it works as neo4j respects numerical order.
It needs a letter character at the beggining though, hence the "a" before the numbers.